# How to solve this com.orientechnologies.common.io.OIOException in orientDb?

Tags: orientdb, orientdb2.2

When I try to update a record with some data I'm getting this exception:

> **Caused by: com.orientechnologies.common.io.OIOException: Impossible to write a chunk of length:83644944 max allowed chunk length:16777216 see NETWORK_BINARY_MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH**  settings
>       at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.OStorageRemote.handleIOException(OStorageRemote.java:321)
>       at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.OStorageRemote.baseNetworkOperation(OStorageRemote.java:296)
>       at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.OStorageRemote.asyncNetworkOperation(OStorageRemote.java:163)
>       at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.OStorageRemote.createRecord(OStorageRemote.java:564)
>       at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.executeSaveRecord(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:2202)
>       at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.tx.OTransactionNoTx.saveNew(OTransactionNoTx.java:241)
>       at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.tx.OTransactionNoTx.saveRecord(OTransactionNoTx.java:171)
>       ... 56 more
>   **Caused by: com.orientechnologies.common.io.OIOException: Impossible to write a chunk of length:83644944 max allowed chunk length:16777216 see NETWORK_BINARY_MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH** settings 
>       at com.orientechnologies.orient.enterprise.channel.binary.OChannelBinary.writeBytes(OChannelBinary.java:273)
>       at com.orientechnologies.orient.enterprise.channel.binary.OChannelBinary.writeBytes(OChannelBinary.java:259)
>       at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.OStorageRemote$5.execute(OStorageRemote.java:571)
>       at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.OStorageRemote$1.execute(OStorageRemote.java:167)
>       at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.OStorageRemote.baseNetworkOperation(OStorageRemote.java:252)
>       ... 61 more

How and where do I need to increase this configuration of maxlength???

My OrientDB version is: 2.2.34

[image of table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Ij1B.jpg)

Here trying to add BINARY data to screenshot column

Answer (score 0):

You can change this setting as follow:

Go into `orientdb-server-config.xml` file and change as follow:

```
<entry name="network.binary.maxLength" value="<a value in KB here>"/>
```

At startup, specifying the following parameter on the command line:

```
-Dnetwork.binary.maxLength=<aValueInKb>

 eg. 

-Dnetwork.binary.maxLength=32768
```

if you are running embedded, you can do the following before you start the server:

```
OGlobalConfiguration.NETWORK_BINARY_MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH.set(32768);
```

Comment: I tried this but it didn't help much .I still get the same exception

Comment: i've added the table structure.please check

Comment: @Sunilkumar3560: Maybe an Orient bug. Check this https://github.com/orientechnologies/OrientDB-NET.binary/issues/140 I've abandoned Orient for Mongo for these brain teasers!